# Line spacing in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

apologies but I am an absolute noob on this. I have implemented a CKeditor on my website using the below HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Define the character set for the HTML element -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <!--Call the external script to use the CDN CKEditor in your page-->
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Define an init function that sends the rich text editor contents to the page code
     function init() {       
       //onMessage runs when the HTML element receives a message from the page code
       window.onmessage = (event) => {  
         if (event.data == "x") {
           CKEDITOR.instances.CK1.setData( '<p></p>' );
console.log(event.data,"ok");
         } else {
    //postMessage sends the contents of the CKEDITOR back to the page code
           window.parent.postMessage(CKEDITOR.instances.CK1.getData(),"*"); 
console.log(event.data,"okd");
    }
       }
     }
     </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init();">
    <!--Define the HTML element as a textarea-->
    <textarea name="editor1" id="CK1"></textarea> 
    <script>
        //Use the CKEditor replace() function to turn our textarea into a CKEditor rich text editor
        CKEDITOR.replace("editor1"); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works great but I have a line spacing issue where it looks like there is a line in between the paragraphs, but when it displays later on it is on top of each other. Is there anyway to reduce the spacing so the user realises they need to press enter again?

Image attached, first test is 1 press of enter after text (which looks like it has a line between but doesn't), second is 2 enters.

My issue is also that I am using Wix, so I can't host the config or whatever files to change. So it all needs to be from the html link.....

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0HXc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to force the user to press Enter twice for a new paragraph? If so, try this:

```
CKEDITOR.addCss('.cke_editable p { margin: 0 !important; }');
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

Comment: Thanks Wizard. As I mentioned in very new to this. Can I add your code to the above and if so Where? And can I not just remove the double spacing altogether?

Comment: Your code has a line `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');` . Add this line `CKEDITOR.addCss('.cke_editable p { margin: 0 !important; }');` on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code will remove extra space

```
:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline p {
  margin: 0;
}
```